# html5 datalist wont dropdown when the sugguest list is large

Tags: jquery, html, html-datalist

I use datalist to suggest a selection of data to a specific text input, but when the size of the datalist got too large( I don't know the right number yet, but quite sure  when the size is larger than 40 this will happen).

I use datalist as following

```
<datalist id="citysuggest">
    <option value="北京">
    <option value="锦州">
    <option value="唐山">
    <option value="天津">
    <option value="清远">
    <option value="盘锦">
    <option value="成都">
</datalist>
<input type="text" list="citysuggest"  name="name1" value="" />
```

here shows when size not "too large", datalist can dropdown when click the down-arrow button.

[image: datalist works ok]

but when datalist is "too large" (in this example the real number is 42), it wont dropdown a  suggest list when click the down-arrow button.

[image: no suggestion pop down]

For the record, this happened with Linux Chrome browser Version 39.0.2171.95

any suggestion to fix that?

Comment: I just found this more like a browser's behavior, when using the same version of chrome in windows, some suggestions will pop up, but not the full datalist, may be because my screen is not large enough? I think a scroll bar of the pop out list will be nice, can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is caused by a known [Cromium bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=375637):

Comment: This is now fixed in Chrome 69

Answer (score -4):

Enclosed your datalist to a div and put overflow:

```
<div style="overflow-x: hidden; overflow: scroll; width: 100%; height:500px"> 
       <datalist id="citysuggest">
    <option value="北京">
    <option value="锦州">
    <option value="唐山">
    <option value="天津">
    <option value="清远">
    <option value="盘锦">
    <option value="成都">
</datalist>
<input type="text" list="citysuggest"  name="name1" value="" />
</div>
```

Hope this helps!